# Logstash Grok regex parsing

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elk

I am trying to do a parsing on a plaintext message using Grok; my goal is to explode the plaintext to a JSON log.

The message has a quite rigid format, as follows:

```
<timestamp> <loglevel> <greedydata> field1=value1, field2=value2, .... fieldN=valueN
```

Where the number of fields is not fixed.

It's possible to capture every field=value pair using a named capturing group, being able to use the same "field" name as the key in the output message?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - use `dissect` instead of `grok`

---

You want something like:

```
{
  "timestamp": <timestamp>,
  "loglevel": <loglevel>,
  "field1": value1,
  "field2": value2,
  ....
  "fieldN": valueN
}
```

Where the keys (`field1`, `fieldN` etc) are dynamic.

You cannot use `grok` to do this. Even using a pattern like this (then using array position indices) won't work:

```
( field[0-9]+=%{DATA:value})+$
```

You need to handle this a different way. Your options are:

- handle this before it hits logstash
- use a `ruby` filter
- use the [`dissect` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html#_indirect_field_notation)